# Detect if awesome is being restarted in rc.lua

Tags: linux, awesome-wm, mate

I'd like to run some stuff when awesome starts, but not run it every time I *restart* it. Is there any way to detect this case? I'm running it under Mate, Linux Mint 16 if that helps at all.

Answer (score 2):

Awesome supports [Signals](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Signals), especially the `exit` signal, which lets you detect if awesome is restarting or not. Maybe you could use this.

Perhaps an easier approach is to use the following:

```
awful.util.spawn_with_shell("pgrep program || program")
```

The `pgrep program` part first checks if there is already some instance of this program running. If not, it gets executed. This of course doesn't work if you want to have you program running on multiple locally running X servers or if it's already started.

`spawn_with_shell` also handles some other parameters, which aren't necessary, but if you're interested, they can be found here:

http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/awful.util.html#spawn_with_shell